# Visual Studio Code—Bulk Import of Files into a Project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an [existing Web site](http://www.hymntime.com/tch) with over 65,000 static HTML, CSS, JavaScript, MIDI, OGG, JPEG & PDF files. I’ve been managing the site with Front Page, and now Expression Web 4 (EW4), for many years, but Microsoft has dropped support for EW4, so I’m shopping around for software to take its place.

I’m currently looking at Visual Studio Code (VSC). The tutorials/videos I’ve seen show how to add files to a VSC project one at a time, but that’s obviously unrealistic with a very large Web site.

So my question is this: **Can I import all my Web site files into a VSC project in a single operation?**

Ideally, I'd like to do something like drag the top level Web site folder into the VSC workspace, then let VSC import all 65K+ files in one fell swoop. I don’t see a way to do that, though it’s entirely possible I’ve missed it. With the current state of my knowledge, reading through all the VSC material online feels like sipping from a fire hose!

Comment: just open your folder with the files as a folder in VSC and thus create a Workspace: **File** | **Open Folder**

Comment: it would be a lot easier to use `/js/hymn.js` instead of `../../../../../js/hymn.js`, and all those other relative paths, use a static web server like Python SimpleWebserver to test the website locally, then you can reference files from the web root folder